# Why is there no Isomorphism?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have a question about he argumentation of this proof.

Problem: Given are two graphs $S$ and $T$. All the vertices in graph $S$ have an degree (number of neighbors) of $3$ and the vertices of $T$ have a degree of $2$ to $5$. For example $v_1 \in V(G)$ with $d(v_1)=4$ 
Is there an Isomorphism from $S$ to $T$?

The argumentation of the Proof is:

There is no Isomorphism from $S$ to $T$ because all vertices of $S$ have an degree of $3$ an and $d(v_1)=4$, so there can not be Isomorphism.

My question would be why? Is it because of the surjectivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An isomorphism $f\colon T\to S$ maps $v_1$ to a vertex $f(v_1)$ of $S$ and its four neighbours $w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4$ to four distinct vertices $f(w_i)$ that are neighbours of $f(v_1)$ - but $f(v_1)$ has only three neighbours!

**Rule of thumb:** Isomorphic thingies are indistinguishable as long as we consider only general thingie-properties. Your graphs $S$ and $T$ can be distinguished by asking "Is there a vertex of degree $\ne 3$?"

Comment: So the problem is the surjectivity of $f$?

Comment: @philipa No. It is possible to have a surjective graph homomorphism as described in the problem statement. It is also possible to have an injective one. The problem is that $S$ and $T$ are too different to be isomorphic